# Angular forms give no value accessor error when I pass formcontrol to child

Tags: angular, input, angular-forms

Why I got an error "no value accessor for form control with unspecified name"?

I have `edit-component`:

html

```
 <mat-form-field>
  <input [formControl]="formControl">
 </mat-form-field>
```

ts:

```
 @Input formControl;
```

In the parent component (main-editor):

html:

```
<edit-component [formControl]="data">
```

ts:

```
get data() {
 return this.form.get('data');
}

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
 this.form = this.fb.group({ data: [''] });
}
```

Comment: Did you try <input [formControlName]="formControl">?

Answer (score 1):

Its because `[formControl]` cannot be set on `edit-component`. If you add reactive inputs to a component you need to implement `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR`.

Change `<edit-component [formControl]="data">` with something else like `<edit-component [myCustomFormControl]="data">` and

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input [formControl]="myCustomFormControl">
 </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Not work because formcontrol and myCustomFormControl is just a name. 
How can I implement NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR for this problem?

Comment: `[formControl]` to a component its not just a name. The @Input() field of your `edit-component` needs to be other than `formControl`, like myCustomFormControl.

Comment: Check the link provided in the other answer, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9kpk3i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html, you will see [formControl] has been replaced with [control] for the "edit-component"

Comment: Thanks! The fact that I named my Input() as 'formControl' was why I was getting this error, even though everything was working!

Answer (score 0):

In `@Input()` decorator we cannot provide `formContolName` as String. we can directly provide a `formControl` but remember this `[AnyOtherName]` instead of `[formControl]`.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <app-test [control]="form.controls.data"></app-test>
</form>
```

check it on a link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9kpk3i?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.html